# Some keys on my Logitech K650 keyboard are actually key combinations. How to remap them?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, logitech-keyboard

I have a Logitech K650 keyboard. It lacks some keys (such as PrtScn key) and replaces them with other "function keys" (See the picture below).
[image]

I try to remap these keys to the functions I need.

[With AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys), I looked at the codes of these keys and found that most them are actually key combinations! For instance, the key with a printer icon is actually `ctrl+p`. The one with a gear icon is actually `win+i`.

If each key has its own code, I can remap them with AHK easily. I can't do that if they are actually key combinations. (Remapping `ctrl+p` would still consume this combination.)

I'm aware of the Logitech Options+ software but I really don't want to use it based on what I heard of it.

My question is: Do these keys have their own "code" I can use in AHK? Is there any other way to remap these keys except Logitech Options+ ?

Comment: I have LogiTech Options 9.7x running on Windows 11 Pro with no issue and an earlier version on Windows 10 Pro when I was on Windows 10. What issues are you having?

Comment: @John That's a long story and I don't want to cluster the question with irrelevant details. I just hope I can get an answer to the questions in my last paragraph: Do these keys have their own "code" I can use in AHK? Is there any other way to remap these keys except Logitech Options+ ?

Comment: Is there any other way to remap these keys except Logitech Options   .....  I am not aware of any other way. Sorry.